# How I can store different type of objects in a generic list in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a requirement to add different type of objects (even though they are different, they share the same base class, they are siblings.

Consider this class hierarchy

```
public abstract class Fruit
{
    public int Quality { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public sealed class Apple :Fruit
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public Apple(string color ="Red")
    {
        Color = color;
    }
}

public sealed class Orange : Fruit
{
    public Orange(string type = "WithSeed")
    {
        Type = type;
    }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do something like this

```
_apples = new List<Apple>
        {
            new Apple
            {
                Name = "Fiji Apple",
                Quality = 9,
                Color ="Green"
            },
            new **Orange**
            {
                Name = "Indi Orange",
                Quality = 7,
            }
        };
```

The consumer of this generic list will use it using the base class. For example: using `IEnumerable<Fruit>`.
Can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Have a list of `Fruit`. That way, the list will hold any `Fruit` object as well as any object of a type that inherits from `Fruit`.

```
List<Fruit> _list = new List<Fruit>
{
    new Apple
    {
        Name = "Fiji Apple",
        Quality = 9,
        Color ="Green"
    },
    new Orange
    {
        Name = "Indi Orange",
        Quality = 7
    }
};
```

Comment: Can it be done without using the Base class. I mean some how, even if different type of objects (apple, orange, pineapple etc.) are passed to prepare this array, they should get projected as apples.

Comment: I don't know what "projected" means in this context.  Do you want the software to make up an Apple based on what you tell it about an Orange?  An Orange has no Color property so how on earth could it do that?  You can't mix apples and oranges ;)

Comment: How would you "project" an `Orange` as an `Apple`? An `Apple` has a bunch of stuff that an `Orange` does not have and vice versa. You would have to create a new `Apple` object that shares as much in common with the original `Orange` object as possible, but then you lose the reference to the original object as well as all of the `Orange` specific information.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common mistake to use class Hierarchies for this purpose.
Have an interface and make a List for that interface instead, then you can even store objects that do not belong to that class hierarchy.

When ever you need to store an object of a different type, just implement the interface in that type, that way you don't have to make any changes to your storage list code.

Answer (score 1):

A list must always know which type it contains. So in order for it to contain both an `Apple` and an `Orange`, you must define the list as containing any super class or interface that covers all items you intent to put in the list.

In this case, that would make `List<Fruit>` or `List<object>` possible to contain both.

Comment: You are correct in that the list itself doesn't need to know anything about the items it contains, it is afterall just a list of pointers or structs internally, which is why 'object' is good enough. The compiler however needs to know, so that it can type check items put into the list.

Answer (score 1):

As all objects inherit from Fruit would be sufficient to create the `List` of `Fruit`

```
 List<Fruit>_apples = new List<Fruit>{...}
```

if I had a class that does `not extend Fruit` would have to create a `List of objects` as **all types (value types and reference predefined and user-defined) are inherited directly or indirectly from `Object`.**

```
List<Object>_apples = new List<Object>{...}
```

Keep in mind that if you do not extend Fruit can not access their attributes like `quality` and `color`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to add different objects in a List

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
            fruits.Add(new Apple("Red"));
            fruits.Add(new Orange("Withseed"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is using a list of different types of `Fruit` just to store them or to pass them along in one `List`, instead of needing seperate `List<Apple>`, `List<Orange>`, etc. But you still need to use the type-specific stuff (like `Apple.Color` and `Orange.Type`).

To demonstrate this I've created a `FruitBasket` class to store all your different `Fruit` objects and `Project()` them with their unique properties.

```
public class FruitBasket
{
    public List<Fruit> FruitList { get; }

    public FruitBasket(List<Fruit> fruitList)
    {
        FruitList = fruitList;
    }

    public List<string> Project()
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var fruit in FruitList)
        {
            if (fruit is Apple)
            {
                var apple = (Apple) fruit;
                result.Add("This is a " + apple.Color + " " + apple.Name);
            }
            else if (fruit is Orange)
            {
                var orange = (Orange) fruit;
                result.Add("A " + orange.Name + " with type: " + orange.Type);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add("An unknown " + fruit.Name);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

While looping through all the different `Fruit` objects, it's checking the type of the fruit and putting a unique string in a list.

The usage of this example would be:

```
var result = new FruitBasket(new List<Fruit>
{
    new Apple
    {
        Name = "Fiji Apple",
        Quality = 9,
        Color = "Green"
    },
    new Orange
    {
        Name = "Indi Orange",
        Quality = 7,
    }
}).Project();
```

And the `result` will be:

> This is a Green Fiji Apple
>
> A Indi Orange with type: WithSeed